# Could not evaluate 'Cosmos.CRTCompat.dll' for extension metadata. Exception message: Bad IL format

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-functions

I'm getting below warning while publishing azure function in Visual Studio 2019.

> Could not evaluate 'Cosmos.CRTCompat.dll' for extension metadata.
>   Exception message: Bad IL format. Could not evaluate
>   'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ServiceInterop.dll' for extension metadata.
>   Exception message: Bad IL format.

I tried the same in a blank project but the same warning coming.

Same issue I can see with VS Code

> C:\Users\pankaj.ra.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.webjobs.script.extensionsmetadatagenerator\1.1.5\build\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator.targets(63,5):
>   warning :     Could not evaluate 'Cosmos.CRTCompat.dll' for extension
>   metadata. Exception message: Bad IL format.

**My function proj file**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
<AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs" Version="4.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.5" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<None Update="host.json">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
<None Update="local.settings.json">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
</None>
</ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you get the same error in a blank project, the problem is hard to troubleshoot. I create a blank function and run it well both in local and azure.

First, clean up all the nuget caches (local & global) and restore everything.

> dotnet nuget locals all --clear

Chances are this is because of a processor architecture mismatch: `loading 64-bit assemblies when you use 32-bit causes this`, for instance.

> If your application uses 32-bit components, make sure that it always runs as a 32-bit application.
>   Make sure that you are not using a component that was created with a different version of the .NET Framework.
>   Make sure that the file image is a valid managed assembly or module.

And, as far as the first item on the list goes:

> If the **Platform target** property for your application project is set to **AnyCPU**, the compiled application can be run in either `64-bit` or `32-bit` mode. When it runs as a 64-bit application, the just-in-time (JIT) compiler produces 64-bit native code. If the application depends on a 32-bit managed or unmanaged component, that component will fail to load in 64-bit mode. To correct this problem, set the project's **Platform target** property to **x86** and recompile.

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/k7137bfe(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Comment: Agree with your answer. Have you tried Azure function in Visual studio 2019?. I have Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise and VS 2019 Community Edition. I don't see this warning when publishing code from VS 2017.

Comment: Both VS17 and 19 both are 32-bit setup. Only the target framework is different - netcoreapp2.1 and 3.1

Comment: I test in vs 2019 and work well. Could you give your test code like what trigger?

Comment: created an eventhub trigger but no custom code. I haven't tried clean NuGet which I'm going to try now

Comment: I test on local and azure with empty eventhub trigger function, both of them work well.

Comment: I think NuGet was an issue